# disable TYPO3 link parsing in html block

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, typo3

In TYPO3 I used html blocks which contains a nav of hash-tags

```
  <li class="navbox default">
    <a href="#c186" title="...">About us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbox default">
    <a href="#c189" title="...">Shop</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbox default">
    <a href="#c202" title="...">Images</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbox default">
    <a href="#c207" title="...">News</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbox default">
    <a href="#c227" title="...">Sale</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbox default">
    <a href="#c194" title="..">Contact us</a>
  </li>
```

This nav is used for Bootstraps Scroll-Spy and the hash-tags represent content-elements. Everything works fine, but only for the page "`/`". If I open the page in another language like `/de.html` or `/en.html`, TYPO3 prepend this part to the href and I get something like this

```
<a href="en.html#c186" title="...">About us</a>
```

This is fine for most cases, but Bootstraps Scroll-Spy expect all links as a "pure" Hash without anything in front.

My question is now, how can I disable TYPO3 parsing of html blocks/link replacement? I don't want to modify the bootstrap js files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.prefixLocalAnchors = 0` is your friend if it is compatible to the rest of your environment (e.g. RealURL configuration):

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html?highlight=prefixlocalanchors

Comment: FYI: I disabled the setting again, because I also used the base-tag which caused some problems. The solution was, just to use the `data-target` attribute instead of `href`

Comment: Thanks a lot !
It's works in my site.
I have got the <a href="/#id">
I need to remove the / before the #id.
config.prefixLocalAnchors = 0  helps .. ! Thanks